# second max value in column for each group in pandas

Tags: pandas, max

```
US_Sales=pd.read_excel("C:\\Users\\xxxxx\\Desktop\\US_Sales.xlsx")
US_Sales

US_Sales.State.nlargest(2,'Sales').groupby(['Sales'])
```

i want second max sales for each city wise

Comment: You may need to look for [`.rank()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.rank.html) instead of `.nlargest()`

Answer (score 0):

- no sample data so simulated
- sort, shift and take first value gives result you want

```
df = pd.DataFrame([{"state":"Florida","sales":[22,4,5,6,7,8]},
             {"state":"California","sales":[99,9,10,11]}]).explode("sales").reset_index(drop=True)

df.sort_values(["state","sales"], ascending=[1,0]).groupby("state").agg({"sales":lambda x: x.shift(-1).values[0]})
```

| state | sales |
| --- | --- |
| California | 11 |
| Florida | 8 |

#### utility function

```
import functools
def nlargest(x, n=2):
    return x.sort_values(ascending=False).shift((n-1)*-1).values[0]
df.groupby("state", as_index=False).agg({"sales":functools.partial(nlargest, n=2)})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can sort the `Sales` column descending, then takes the 2nd row with [pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.nth()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.nth.html) in each group. Note that `n` in `nth()` is zero indexed.

```py
US_Sales.sort_values(['State', 'Sales'], ascending=[True, False]).groupby('State').nth(1).reset_index()
```

You can also choose the largest 2 values then keep the last by various methods:

```py
largest2 = df.sort_values(['State', 'Sales'], ascending=[True, False]).groupby('State')['Sales'].nlargest(2)

# Method 1
# Drop duplicates by `State`, keep the last one
largest2.reset_index().drop('level_1', axis=1).drop_duplicates(['State'], keep='last')

# Method 2
# Group by `State`, keep the last one
largest2.groupby('State').tail(1).reset_index().drop('level_1', axis=1)
```